# React context doesn't transfer when using a component as prop

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap's ModalTrigger to show a field-heavy modal (based on react-bootstrap's Modal), which means sending it a bunch of props:

```
<ModalTrigger modal={<MyModal field1={value1} field2={value2} (more fields...)/>}>
    Click here to open
</ModalTrigger>
```

The parent component that creates the trigger has the fields/values passed in via props, and the parent component of *that* component has it passed as props as well, by the top-level component that actually holds the data. Both are basically pipes, which is a classic childContext scenario, except that it doesn't work. Here's a simplified version of what I've tried:

```
var MyModal = React.createClass({
    contextTypes : {foo : React.PropTypes.string},
    render : function() {
        return (
            <Modal {...this.props} title="MyTitle">
                <div className="modal-body">
                    The context is {this.context.foo}
                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
    childContextTypes : {foo: React.PropTypes.string},
    getChildContext : function() {return {foo : "bar"}},
    render : function() {
        return (
            <ModalTrigger modal={<MyModal/>}>
                <span>Show modal</span>
            </ModalTrigger>
        )
    }
});
```

The modal pops up with "The context is", without showing the actual context.

I believe this is happening because the prop sent to ModalTrigger is already rendered/mounted somehow, but I'm not sure why. To the best of my understanding, the owner of MyModal is the Content component, which means that the context should be ok, but this is not the case.

Some more information: I already tried passing `{...this.props}` and `context={this.context}` to MyModal with no success. Also, maybe relevant, ModalTrigger uses cloneElement to make sure the modal's onRequestHide prop points to the trigger's hide function.

So what am I missing here? :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`React.cloneElement` will change the owner of the element when the `ref` prop is overriden, which means context will not be passed from the previous owner. **However, this does not seem to be the case with `ModalTrigger`.**

Note that the owner-based approach won't work altogether in React 0.14, since  context will be passed from parent to child and not from owner to ownee anymore. `ModalTrigger` renders its `modal` node prop in another branch of the DOM (See [`OverlayMixin`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/OverlayMixin.js)). Thus, your `Modal` component is not a child nor a descendant of your `Content` component and won't be passed child context from `Content`.

As for solving your problem, you can always create a component whose sole purpose is to pass context to its children.

```js
var PassContext = React.createClass({
  childContextTypes: {
    foo: React.PropTypes.string
  },

  getChildContext: function() {
    return this.props.context;
  },

  render: function() {
    return <MyModal />;
  },
});
```

To use it:

```js
<ModalTrigger modal={<PassContext context={this.getChildContext()}/>}>
```

As Matt Smith hinted, it turns out that react-bootstrap already includes a very similar approach to forwarding context via [`ModalTrigger.withContext`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/3b33652f7fe424f129af6a178411cc9fe67ed988/src/ModalTrigger.js#L65-78). This allows you to create a `ModalTrigger` component class which will forward its context to its `modal` node prop, no matter its position in the VDOM tree.

```js
// MyModalTrigger.js
module.exports = ModalTrigger.withContext({
  foo: React.PropTypes.String
});
```

Comment: Since context is an undocumented feature of react we have not documented this capability yet. For details though check out https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/644. Jimmy has done some great work to enable your usage of contexts.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware about the `cloneElement` behavior..
Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "this approach won't work" ?

Comment: It turns out my previous description of the behavior of `cloneElement` was wrong: owner will be preserved unless the `ref` prop is overriden, which doesn't seem to be the case for `ModalTrigger`. I've updated my answer with a correction, as well as a cleaner solution to your problem that comes bundled with react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better way of passing context on to your "portal" type components which render their children into a different container outside the React tree.

Using "renderSubtreeIntoContainer" rather than "render" will pass the context into the subtree as well.

It can be used like so:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
    unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer as renderSubtreeIntoContainer,
    unmountComponentAtNode
} from 'react-dom';

export default class extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'ReactPortal';

  static propTypes = {
    isRendered: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    portalContainer: PropTypes.node
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    isRendered: true
  };

  state = {
    mountNode: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isRendered) {
      this._renderPortal();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.isRendered && !this.props.isRendered ||
      (prevProps.portalContainer !== this.props.portalContainer &&
         prevProps.isRendered)) {
      this._unrenderPortal();
    }

    if (this.props.isRendered) {
      this._renderPortal();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unrenderPortal();
  }

  _getMountNode = () => {
    if (!this.state.mountNode) {
      const portalContainer = this.props.portalContainer || document.body;
      const mountNode = document.createElement('div');
      portalContainer.appendChild(mountNode);
      this.setState({
        mountNode
      });

      return mountNode;
    }

    return this.state.mountNode;
  };

  _renderPortal = () => {
    const mountNode = this._getMountNode();
    renderSubtreeIntoContainer(
      this,
      (
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      ),
      mountNode,
    );
  };

  _unrenderPortal = () => {
    if (this.state.mountNode) {
      unmountComponentAtNode(this.state.mountNode);
      this.state.mountNode.parentElement.removeChild(this.state.mountNode);
      this.setState({
        mountNode: null
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
};
```

This is an example of a portal I use in my [production app Casalova](https://www.casalova.ca) that render context properly into their children.

Note: this API is undocumented and is likely to change in the future. For now, though, it's the right way to render context into portal components.

Comment: hey - what do you mean by "portal components"?